# How to list out all the h2, h3, and p tags then create a dataframe to store them

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I had given a website to scrape all of the key items

But the output I got is only for one item using `BeautifulSoup4`. So wonder if I need to use anything like `soup.findall` to extract all the key items in a list from the website.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url=
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

column= soup.find(class_ = re.compile('columns is-multiline'))
print(column.prettify())

position = column.h2.text
company = column.h3.text
city_state= column.find_all('p')[-2].text
print (position, company, city_state)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://realpython.github.io/fake-jobs/'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

positions = [pos.text for pos in soup.find_all('h2')]

companies = [com.text for com in soup.find_all('h3')]

city_state0 = []
city_state1 = []
for p in soup.find_all('p', {'class' : 'location'}):
    city_state0.append(p.text.split(',')[0].strip())
    city_state1.append(p.text.split(',')[1].strip())

    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'city_state1': city_state0,
    'city_state2': city_state1,
    'companies' : companies,
    'positions' : positions
})
print(df)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @jane welcome and if this correct please read this link : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Just another question, do you think I can break the city and state so that e.g. Stewartbury and AA are in different columns?

Comment: yes this is possible

Comment: @jane see edited answer, is this correct

Comment: Hi ,just a problem, I think all the state are starting AA, AP etc., some of the name of the city becomes city_state2

Comment: As some city has two words, so would want to something like city_state 1 are North Jamieview, Davidville, While city_state are all the AA, AP.

Comment: @jane OK how get this data?

Comment: from https://realpython.github.io/fake-jobs/

Comment: @jane oh, you are right, edited answer, is this correct now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `find_all` to get all the elements like so. `find` only gets the first element.

```py
titles = soup.find_all('h2', class_='title is-5')
companies = soup.find_all('h3', class_='subtitle is-6 company')
locations = soup.find_all('p', class_='location')
# loop over locations and extract the city and state
for location in locations:
   city = location.split(', ')[0]
   state = location.split(', ')[1]
```

Comment: Ok, will have a try thanks